# How can I run an app that requires OpenGL 3.3 if I have Intel GMA 4500M with OpenGL 2.1 support?

Tags: opengl, intel, emulation

Similar question already exists on this forum but I can't understand: is there really no way to emulate OpenGL on CPU? To be honest, I don't understant completely how OpenGL works. I have an integrated card, Intel GMA 4500M, it supports OpenGL 2.1 only, but I can't buy new laptop now. I need to use Element 3D plug-in for After Effects but it supports OpenGL 3.3. Why I can't emulate OpenGL functions on CPU only?

Answer (score 3):

> is there really no way to emulate OpenGL on CPU?

Of course there is, it's just not widely deployed.

> Why I can't emulate OpenGL functions on CPU only?

Because that's another piece of software that must be installed, and may conflict with other parts of the system. And since OpenGL's main purpose is to interface GPUs not many people care.

There's MesaGL which has a software rasterizer backend. There are Windows builds of MesaGL which contain only said software rasterizer. You can place copies of MesaGL's opengl32.dll in the directories/folders of the programs you want to use that.